# Function Show CRUD not working in Controller.php

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.4

I'm using laravel 8 for CRUD.. i try using create and store function in controller and it's perfecly fine then the data will store in database. Now, i try to use show function which the data that i created will show to user once they click the 'show' button. The most error i found is undefined $product

here is my blade for index.blade

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="show-index">Show</a>
```

Here is my blade for show.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
<div class="pull-left">
<h2> Show Product</h2>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="pro_index"> Back</a
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
<strong>Name:</strong>
{{ $product->name }}
</div>
 </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
 <strong>Details:</strong>
{{ $product->detail }}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my ProductController.php

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
  $products = Product::all();
  return view('products.pro_index',compact('products'));
 }

 public function create()
 {
  return view('products.create');
 {

 public function store(Request $request)
 {
  $request->validate([
   'name' => 'required',
   'detail' => 'required',
  ]);

  $product= Product::create([
   'name' => $request->name,
   'detail' => $request->detail,
  ]);

  return redirect('/pro_index') ->with('success','Your record has been updated');
 }

 public function show (Product $product)
 {
  $product = Product::find($product);
  return view('products.show');
 }
}
```

here is my web.php

```
Route::get('/show-index', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```

Comment: return view('products.show')->with(compact('product'));

Comment: Use like this`href="{{ route('show', $product->id) }}`

Answer (score 1):

Change anchor href from  `href="show-index"` to `href="{{ route('show', $product) }}`

In controller

```
public function show (Product $product)
{
  return view('products.show', compact('product'));
}
```

in web.php

```
Route::get('/show/{product}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'show'])
->name('show');
```

For more : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: working but the input data that i already put will not show in show.blade...

Comment: {{ $product->detail }} in show.blade not working properly...

Comment: can you show me simplest column in show.blade

Comment: use `dd($product)` at `show.blade.php`  at the top to see what you get

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line of code because you already have model binding in place

`$product = Product::find($product);`